# What is difference between spring's netflix and netflix

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix

Spring framework has a Netflix OSS and its integration. I wonder that spring has a special change like a patch for Netflix OSS.
I mean spring's Netflix zuul and Netflix's zuul are completely same thing, as a source code and so on?

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Cloud Netflix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-netflix) provides auto-configuration and binding to other Spring idioms, so that you can easily integrate projects like Eureka, Ribbon or Hystrix with Spring Boot applications.

For example, you can enable the Eureka discovery client in a Spring Boot application by simply having the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency on your classpath and adding some corresponding configuration properties:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Please note most of the Spring Cloud Netflix components (including Hystrix, Ribbon and Zuul) are in [maintenance mode](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode) and have been replaced with other projects.